# Get biggest volume on specified disk

Tags: powershell, storage

Edit : I realized that I might have posted in the wrong place, might be better to send it to serverfault, sorry if so.

I'm looking into the automation of a disk restoration operation, and in the middle of it I need to assign a letter to the restored Volume containing the Windows system to allow modification of it's content (driver injection, etc).

On the machine I have 2 disks : Disk 0 is the system disk of the restorING machine and disk 1 is the system disk of the restorED machine on which there are two partitions, system reserved and the standard one.

I would like to assign the drive letter E to the 
Disk 1 Partition Windows. Like this after doing it manually:

```
Get-Partition

Disk Number: 1
PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                 Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                 ---- ----
1                            1048576                              350 MB IFS
2                E           368050176                          29.66 GB IFS

 Disk Number: 0
PartitionNumber  DriveLetter Offset                                 Size Type
---------------  ----------- ------                                 ---- ----
1                            1048576                              350 MB IFS
2                C           368050176                          49.66 GB IFS
```

What I tried :

```
Get-Partition -DiskNumber 1 | Where-Object -FilterScript {$_.Type -Eq "Basic"} |
    Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter E
```

This doesn't work because the Where object condition is not detecting a basic type.

I thought maybe that I could try to detect the biggest partition because there will only ever be two partition on the disk. But how, I don't know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you'd like to get the largest partition, you can use Sort-Object on the size property, which is type uint64 - so you don't have to worry about grabbing the wrong one based on string sorting of MB/GB - and then just take the first result using Select-Object, like so:

```
Get-Partition -DiskNumber 1 | Sort-Object "Size" -Descending | Select-object -First 1 |  Set-Partition -NewDriveLetter E
```

Answer (score 4):

This selects the biggest partition on disk 1:

```
Get-Partition -DiskNumber 1 | sort-object -property size -descending | select -first 1
```

hope that helps